# How can I modify the default behavior of Aptana's terminal windows? (I can't find any doc about them.)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, aptana, aptana3

I am very (VERY) new to Aptana and I'm just trying to figure out enough about how it works to help get it out of my way while I try and learn a little bit about Ruby on Rails.

In the Web perspective (?) I currently have active (open?), Aptana has two terminal icons in the vicinity of the lower left corner of its window. One pops up the description "Create a Terminal View" and the other "Create a Terminal Editor".

So what heck is the difference between a Terminal View versus Editor? The terminology means nothing to me. I've tried Googling, but I don't hit on anything that seems relevant. I've tried searching the Aptana help documentation. Again, **nothing**. (I thought there would at *least* be the non-helpful help text that "This opens a terminal window". But no hits when I search???

Am I just doing the search wrong?

The only difference I notice between View versus Editor is they open in different sections of the Apatana window. Terminal Editors always open in the section where Aptana open text editor windows. Terminal Views are placed in the same section where the Console and Problem windows go. [woo-hoo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woo-hoo).

I am able to "float" ... detach from the main Aptana window ... only the Terminal View windows. Terminal Editor windows stay stubbornly glued to the main Apatana window.

But even if I do pull a Terminal View window out to stand by itself, then it is *ALWAYS* on top of the original, main Aptana window I detached it from. And I cannot figure out how to change this very irritating behavior.

Can anyone tell me more about these ill-mannered terminal windows? Can they be taught to play nicer?

Copied below is some information about my setup just in case anyone is curious.

```
Host OS: Linux
OS Arch: x86
JRE Version: 1.6.0_23
JRE Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
JRE Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Install Directory: file:~/Aptana Studio 3/
Version: 3.0.9.201202141038
VM Arguments: -Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
3/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to any of my questions, just the work-around I'll be using to avoid dealing with whatever those things are that Aptana euphemistically refers to as "terminal" windows. (I'm just sayin' ...)

It's a pretty brain dead work-around. In one of the Aptana terminal windows type

```
 gnome-terminal&
```

In other words, just open separate Ubuntu (in my case) terminal windows and pretty much ignore Aptana's. Folks using other flavors of linux would of course use the command to open a new terminal window appropriate to their distribution.

I'll leave this problem open for a bit longer in case anyone else wants to offer something.

That will also give the moderators a chance to decide if they want to move this question over to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), which might be a better home? Or not. In my partial defense, I think I read somewhere that the Aptana developers monitor stackoverflow for questions tagged [Aptana].